# I can't get this Apps Script function to work in Google Spreadsheet (saving number of Twitter followers)

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

This is my first question on Stackoverflow, so I apologise in advance if there is something wrong with the post.

I've been trying to build a simple function in my Spreadsheet using online tutorials. The objective is following:

1) Download number of followers for a given Twitter account 
2) Save the date the data was accessed 
3) Repeat weekly

I download the number of followers using this code (it refers to A1 where there is the link to the twitter account):

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTXML(A1,"//a[@data-nav='followers']"),"select Col3"),QUERY(IMPORTXML(A1&"/","//a[@data-nav='followers']"),"select Col3"))
```

I'm trying to use the following script to now save the date and repeat this operation every week:

```
function storeFollowers() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); /** holds name of active spreadsheet**/
  var datarange = sheet.getDataRange(); /** defines where cells have data **/ 
  var numRows = datarange.getNumRows(); /** save numRows to number of rows in the sheet **/
  var numColumns = datarange.getNumColumns(); /** store number of columns in the sheet **/
  var nextColumn = numColumns + 1; /** first empty column **/ 
  sheet.getRange(1, nextColumn).setValue(new Date());
  for (var i=2; i <= numRows; i++){
    var numLikes = sheet.GetRange(i, 3).getValue();
sheet.getRange(i, numColumns +1).setValue(numLikes);
  }
}
```

When I try to execute it, I keep getting this error:

"TypeError: Cannot find function GetRange in object Sheet. (line 9, file "Code")"

Any idea how this can be fixed? I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `GetRange()` function in sheets object, the function you are looking for it `getRange()`. 
**Note** that it is small letter 'g' and not capital letter 'G'. Google script functions are case sensitive!

Please modify this line

```
var numLikes = sheet.GetRange(i, 3).getValue();
```

to this

```
var numLikes = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
```